# Difference between UWP and Xamarin's UWP?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I was trying to learn basics of xamarin. I came across [Adding a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) App](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/) and I was trying to figure out advantages of using it over normal UWA with PCL or Shared projects. Is it different from UWP, or does it offers more support from portability?

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin Forms helps dev code once and deploy on cross-platforms. 
For front end, there are bit different when you code UWP and Xamarin Forms. stackpanel and stacklayout these kind of UI element. MS is working on XAML standard 1.0 so in future we only have one XAML need to remember.

If you are working on windows 10 app, highly recommended using UWP. There are more docs you can read.
Lot of people using Xamarin Forms to create Android iOS cross-platform apps, and devs lost interesting in support xamarin forms plugins for UWP.

Answer (score 0):

> does it offers more support from portability

Yes, or rather I should say that portability is the only practical reason you want to use Xamarin (aside from you being familiar with the platform and not wanting to learn something new, but this seems not to be the case).

> Is it different from UWP

As far as I know, Xamarin's UWP is just a UWP project included inside a Xamarin project, so it's basically the same thing.

Comment: Can you explain how it offers more portability? I mean if you only have to use shared project or PCLs to share code between xamarin.andriod and xamarin.iOS.

Comment: If you only need android and iOS but not UPW, then simply remove the UWP project.

Comment: the XAML code defining a Xamarin Forms GUI is common between OS Platforms...or at least you can clone the same XAML code between ios and android projects...

Comment: @BillMoore - or instead of "cloning", make a shared PCL containing the XAML. The standard template for Xamarin Forms creates such a PCL. For example, if you are developing for iOS and Android, you will have *three* projects: one for each platform with any custom renderers and other custom code, and one with the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: NO
No performance issues
No developing issues
Everything was converted down to the same assembly and run as you expected
However, if you just do mainly in UWP. I suggest not doing it on Xamarin, because the support of new toys come a little bit slower on Xamarin. Right now the communities are waiting for XamlUI Alpha